# How to download LoadRunner performance testing tool?

Tags: performance, testing, loadrunner

How to download LoadRunner performance testing tool?
When I try to download from the Micro Focus website which is there official website, they are not allowing me to download the trial version instead they have a form which we need to fill and then they will show a message saying "We will connect with you soon".

Please help me by informing me how to download the trial version of Loadrunner?

Answer (score 0):

You are in the correct path.  They will contact you and provide a download link for your evaluation of their product